# Removing similar but longer duplicates from vector

Tags: r, regex, vector, set

For database cleanup, I have a vector of, say, dishes and I want to remove all the variants of the "base" dish, keeping only the base dish. For instance, if I have...

```
dishes <- c("DAL BHAT", "DAL BHAT-(SPICY)", "DAL BHAT WITH EXTRA RICE", 
            "HAMBURGER", "HAMBURGER-BIG", "HAMBURGER2", "PIZZA", 
            "PIZZA (PROSCIUTO)", "PIZZA_BOLOGNESE")
```

... I want to remove all entries that already have a shorter matching version in the vector. The resulting vector would thus only include: "DAL BHAT", "HAMBURGER, "PIZZA".

Using a nested `for` loop and checking everything against all others will work for this example, but will take long for the large dataset at hand and is furthermore ugly coding I'd say.

It can be assumed that all entries are in caps and that the vector is already sorted. It cannot be assumed that the first item of the next base dish is always shorter than the previous entry.

Any suggestions on how to solve this in an efficient way?

*BONUS QUESTION*: Ideally, I only want to remove items from the initial vector if they are at least 3 characters longer than their shorter counterpart. In the above case, that would mean that "HAMBURGER2" would also be retained in the resulting vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the approach I'd take with this. I'd create a function with some of the conditions that I'd need to consider, and use that on the input. I've added comments to explain what's happening in the function.

The function has 4 arguments:

- `invec`: The input character vector.
- `thresh`: How many characters can we use to determine the "base" dish. Default = 5.
- `minlen`: Your "BONUS" question. Default = 3.
- `strict`: Logical. If there are base dishes with `nchar` shorter than your `thresh`, do you want to lower the thresh or be strict about what you're looking at for the base? Default = `FALSE`. See the last example for how `strict` might work.

---

```
myfun <- function(invec, thresh = 5, minlen = 3, strict = FALSE) {
  # Bookkeeping -- sort, unique, all upper case
  invec <- sort(unique(toupper(invec)))
  # More bookkeeping -- min should not be longer 
  # than min base dish unless strict = TRUE
  thresh <- if (isTRUE(strict)) thresh else min(min(nchar(invec)), thresh)
  # Use `thresh` to get the `stubs``
  stubs <- invec[!duplicated(substr(invec, 1, thresh))]
  # loop through the stubs and do two things:
  #   - Match the dish with the stub
  #   - Return the base dish and any dishes within the minlen
  unlist(
    lapply(stubs, function(x) {
      temp <- grep(x, invec, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
      temp[temp == x | nchar(temp) <= nchar(x) + minlen]
      }), 
    use.names = FALSE)
}
```

Your sample data:

```
dishes <- c("DAL BHAT", "DAL BHAT-(SPICY)", "DAL BHAT WITH EXTRA RICE", 
            "HAMBURGER", "HAMBURGER-BIG", "HAMBURGER2", "PIZZA", 
            "PIZZA (PROSCIUTO)", "PIZZA_BOLOGNESE")
```

Here's the result:

```
myfun(dishes, minlen = 0)
# [1] "DAL BHAT"  "HAMBURGER" "PIZZA" 

myfun(dishes)
# [1] "DAL BHAT"   "HAMBURGER"  "HAMBURGER2" "PIZZA"
```

Here's some more sample data. Note that in "dishes2" the data are no longer sorted and there's a new item "DAL", and in "dishes3" you also have lowercase dishes.

```
dishes2 <- c("DAL BHAT", "DAL BHAT-(SPICY)", "DAL BHAT WITH EXTRA RICE", 
             "HAMBURGER", "HAMBURGER-BIG", "HAMBURGER2", "PIZZA", 
             "PIZZA (PROSCIUTO)", "PIZZA_BOLOGNESE", "DAL")

dishes3 <- c("DAL BHAT", "DAL BHAT-(SPICY)", "DAL BHAT WITH EXTRA RICE", 
             "HAMBURGER", "HAMBURGER-BIG", "HAMBURGER2", "PIZZA", 
             "PIZZA (PROSCIUTO)", "PIZZA_BOLOGNESE", "DAL", "pizza!!")
```

Here's the function on those vectors:

```
myfun(dishes2, 4)
# [1] "DAL"        "HAMBURGER"  "HAMBURGER2" "PIZZA"   

myfun(dishes3)
# [1] "DAL"        "HAMBURGER"  "HAMBURGER2" "PIZZA"      "PIZZA!!"  

myfun(dishes3, strict = TRUE)
# [1] "DAL"        "DAL BHAT"   "HAMBURGER"  "HAMBURGER2" "PIZZA"      "PIZZA!!"
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested *to remove all entries that already have a shorter matching version in the vector*. In addition, the OP *wants to remove items from the initial vector if they are at least 3 characters longer than their shorter counterpart*.

The *brute force* method would try to compare all entries with each other to find if one string is part of the other string. This  would require *n x (n-1)* comparisons.

The approach below tries to reduce the number of string comparisons by checking the number of characters beforehand. This will at least halven the number of calls to `grepl()`.

```
library(data.table)
# prepare data
DT <- data.table(dish = dishes)[, len := nchar(dish)][order(len)]
DT
```

> ```
>                         dish len
>  1:                      NAN   3
>  2:                    PIZZA   5
>  3:                 DAL BHAT   8
>  4:                HAMBURGER   9
>  5:               HAMBURGER2  10
>  6:            HAMBURGER-BIG  13
>  7:           SLICE OF PIZZA  14
>  8:          PIZZA_BOLOGNESE  15
>  9:         DAL BHAT-(SPICY)  16
> 10:        PIZZA (PROSCIUTO)  17
> 11: DAL BHAT WITH EXTRA RICE  24
> ```

```
# use non-equi join to find row numbers of "duplicate" entries
tmp <- DT[.(len + 3L, dish), on = .(len > V1), nomatch = 0L, allow = TRUE,
          by = .EACHI, .I[grepl(V2, dish)]]
tmp
```

> ```
>    len V1
> 1:   8  7
> 2:   8  8
> 3:   8 10
> 4:  11  9
> 5:  11 11
> 6:  12  6
> ```

```
# anti-join to remove "duplicates"
DT[!tmp$V1, dish]
```

> ```
> [1] "NAN"        "PIZZA"      "DAL BHAT"   "HAMBURGER"  "HAMBURGER2"
> ```

#### Edit

Due to the *non-equi join* this approach works also *without* reordering `DT` beforehand:

```
delta_len <- 3L
DT <- data.table(dish = dishes)[, len := nchar(dish)]
DT[!DT[.(len + delta_len, dish), on = .(len > V1), nomatch = 0L, allow = TRUE,
       by = .EACHI, .I[grepl(V2, dish)]]$V1, dish]
```

> ```
> [1] "DAL BHAT"   "HAMBURGER"  "HAMBURGER2" "PIZZA"      "NAN"
> ```

This has the benefit that the original order of `dishes` is maintained (with the "duplicates" removed).

#### Data

```
dishes <- c("DAL BHAT", "DAL BHAT-(SPICY)", "DAL BHAT WITH EXTRA RICE", 
            "HAMBURGER", "HAMBURGER-BIG", "HAMBURGER2", "PIZZA", 
            "PIZZA (PROSCIUTO)", "PIZZA_BOLOGNESE", "NAN", "SLICE OF PIZZA")
```

Note that two items have been added to cover additional test cases.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using `sapply` with `grepl` and `colSums`:

```
dishes[colSums(sapply(dishes, function(x) grepl(x, setdiff(dishes, x)))) > 0]
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] "DAL BHAT"  "HAMBURGER" "PIZZA"
> ```

What this does:

- `sapply(dishes, function(x) grepl(x, setdiff(dishes, x)))` compares each element of `dishes` with the other elements and looks with `grepl` whether the specific element is a part of the other elements.
- This returns a logical matrix, where a `TRUE` value indicates whether a *dish name* is part of another *dish name*:

  > ```
  >      DAL BHAT DAL BHAT-(SPICY) DAL BHAT WITH EXTRA RICE HAMBURGER HAMBURGER-BIG HAMBURGER2 PIZZA PIZZA (PROSCIUTO) PIZZA_BOLOGNESE
  > [1,]     TRUE            FALSE                    FALSE     FALSE         FALSE      FALSE FALSE             FALSE           FALSE
  > [2,]     TRUE            FALSE                    FALSE     FALSE         FALSE      FALSE FALSE             FALSE           FALSE
  > [3,]    FALSE            FALSE                    FALSE     FALSE         FALSE      FALSE FALSE             FALSE           FALSE
  > [4,]    FALSE            FALSE                    FALSE      TRUE         FALSE      FALSE FALSE             FALSE           FALSE
  > [5,]    FALSE            FALSE                    FALSE      TRUE         FALSE      FALSE FALSE             FALSE           FALSE
  > [6,]    FALSE            FALSE                    FALSE     FALSE         FALSE      FALSE FALSE             FALSE           FALSE
  > [7,]    FALSE            FALSE                    FALSE     FALSE         FALSE      FALSE  TRUE             FALSE           FALSE
  > [8,]    FALSE            FALSE                    FALSE     FALSE         FALSE      FALSE  TRUE             FALSE           FALSE
  > ```
- By taking the column sum with `colSums`, you get a numeric vector of how many other *dishes* the name of each *dish* contains:

  > ```
  > DAL BHAT   DAL BHAT-(SPICY) DAL BHAT WITH EXTRA RICE  HAMBURGER  HAMBURGER-BIG    HAMBURGER2    PIZZA    PIZZA (PROSCIUTO)   PIZZA_BOLOGNESE 
  >        2                  0                        0          2              0             0        2                    0                 0
  > ```
- Only the shorter *dish names* have a count larger than zero. Consequently, comparing the numeric vector with zero returns a logical vector of which *dishes* to keep.
- As an alternative to using `> 0`, you can also use a double negation sign (`!!`) in front of `colSums`. This also selects the elements that have a count not equal to zero: `dishes[!!colSums(sapply(dishes, function(x) grepl(x, setdiff(dishes, x))))]`.

---

If you want to take into account a maximum difference in character length, then you can use `agrepl` instead of `grepl` where you can specify the maximum edit difference in characters with the `max.distance`-parameter:

```
dishes[colSums(sapply(dishes, function(x) agrepl(x, setdiff(dishes, x), max.distance = 3))) > 0]
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] "DAL BHAT"   "HAMBURGER"  "HAMBURGER2" "PIZZA"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
unlist(sapply(split(dishes, substr(dishes, 1, 5)), function(x){
    N = nchar(x)
    x[(N - N[1]) < 3]
}))
#       DAL B       HAMBU1       HAMBU2        PIZZA 
#  "DAL BHAT"  "HAMBURGER" "HAMBURGER2"      "PIZZA"
```